# Can someone explain why my for loop stops at the wrong place

Tags: c

Sorry if this is a dumb mistake I'm just a beginner. I'm answering a question in the book C programming a modern approach. This asks to print all even squares between 1 and the number given.

This is my original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int n, i;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf ("%d", &n);

  for (int i = 2; i <= n ; i += 2) {
    printf("%d %d\n", i * i, n);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it will only stop once it hits ten thousand so I divided "n" inside the for loop:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n / 10 ; i += 2) {
  printf("%d %d\n", i * i, n);
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happens

Comment: What number did you type in?

Comment: I used the number 100

Comment: You stop when `i` is greater than the number given, not when `i * i` is greater than the number given. It just happened to work correctly when you divided it `n / 10`, but that was purely coincidence with you entering 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the loop check should be `i * i <= n` this if you want the squares to stop before `n`

```
  for (int i = 2; i * i <= n ; i += 2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is prints the square of each even number from `2` to `n`. For example lets go through the loop a few times:

1. `i = 2`, `n = 100`
2. `i = 4`, `n = 100`
3. `i = 6`, `n = 100`

...

48. `i = 96`, `n = 100`
49. `i = 98`, `n = 100`
50. `i = 100`, `n = 100`

On the 51st time you add 2 to `i` it will be 102, which is larger than `n`, so the loop will exit.

To print all the even squares up to `n` you'd want to do something more like:

```
for(auto i = 2, j = i * i; n >= j; i += 2; j = i * i){
    printf("%d %d\n", j, n);
}
```

Note that the `,` in the `for` condition lets me do more than one initialization and more than one increment, so I'm stepping `i` by 2 and `j` is just reassigned the square of `i` each increment.